# URL.createObjectURL working in some components and not in others ReacrJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using `URL.createObjectURL` to create image and pass it to an other component. In my NotificationStepper `URL.createObjectURL` is working just fine but in another Createwebsite component is i am getting this error **TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.**.
following is my NotificationStepper component.

```
const styles = {
    transparentBar: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        paddingTop: '25px',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    dialogPaper: {
        minHeight: '400px',
        maxHeight: '400px',
    },
};

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
    createStyles({
        formControl: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            minWidth: 120,
        },
        selectEmpty: {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        },
    }),
);

function getSteps() {
    return ['Create', 'Audience', 'Timing'];
}




function getStepContent(step, $this) {
            return (
                <div className="row">

                    <CardBox styleName="col-lg-12"
                        heading="">
                        <form className="row" noValidate autoComplete="off" style={{ "flex-wrap": "no-wrap", "flex-direction": "column" }}>
                            <div className="col-md-12 col-12" style={{ "margin-bottom": "15px", "display": "flex", "align-items": "center" }}>
                                <Tooltip title="Use featured image of the landing page here. Works on Chrome, Opera, Edge. Recommended aspect ratio 2:1. Jpg, Jpeg, PNG file types only.">
                                    <IconButton aria-label="">
                                        <HelpOutlineIcon />
                                    </IconButton>
                                </Tooltip>
                                <span style={{ "width": "20%", "margin-right": "20px" }}>Banner: </span>
                                <div className="inputfile">
                                    Upload
                                    <input className='hide_file' type="file" onChange={$this.onBannerChange} />
                                </div>
                                {$this.state.banner ?
                                    <span>{$this.state.icon.banner}</span>
                                    : null
                                }

                            </div>

                        </form>
                </div >
            );
        }


class NotificationStepper extends React.Component {

    state = {
        banner: '',
        crop: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        zoom: 1,
        aspect: 1,
        croppedAreaPixels: null,
        croppedImage: null,
        showDialog: false,
    };

    onBannerChange = event => {
        this.setState({ banner: event.target.files[0] });
        this.setState({showDialog: true})
    };

    onIconChange = event => {
        this.setState({ icon: event.target.files[0] });
        this.setState({showDialogIcon: true})

    };

    onCropChange = crop => {
        this.setState({ crop })
    };

    onCropComplete = (croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
        this.setState({croppedAreaPixels: croppedAreaPixels});
    };

    CropImageBanner = async ()=> {
        const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(
            URL.createObjectURL(this.state.banner),
            this.state.croppedAreaPixels,
            0
        );
        this.setState({ banner: croppedImage });
        this.closeDialog();
    };
    closeDialog = () => {
        this.setState({showDialog: false});
    }

    onZoomChange = zoom => {
        this.setState({ zoom })
    };


    render() {
        const steps = getSteps();
        const { activeStep } = this.state;

        if (this.props.showSuccessMessage) {
            console.log('dispatch');
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.hideMessage();
            }, 100);
        }
        if (this.props.showMessage) {
            console.log('dispatch');
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.hideCompaignAlert();
            }, 100);
        }
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.banner ?
                            // <span>{$this.state.banner.name}</span>
                    <Dialog
                        classes={{paper: classes.dialogPaper }}
                        fullWidth={true}
                        maxWidth='sm'
                        open={this.state.showDialog}
                        onClose={this.closeDialog}
                    >
                        <DialogTitle>
                        </DialogTitle>
                        <DialogContent>
                            <div className="App-crop" >
                                <div className="crop-container-div">
                                    <Cropper
                                        image={URL.createObjectURL(this.state.banner)}
                                        crop={this.state.crop}
                                        zoom={this.state.zoom}
                                        aspect={this.state.aspect}
                                        onCropChange={this.onCropChange}
                                        onCropComplete={this.onCropComplete}
                                        onZoomChange={this.onZoomChange}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="controls">
                                    <Slider
                                        value={this.state.zoom}
                                        min={1}
                                        max={3}
                                        step={0.1}
                                        aria-labelledby="Zoom"
                                        onChange={(e, zoom) => this.onZoomChange(zoom)}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </DialogContent>
                        <DialogActions>
                            <Button onClick={() => this.closeDialog()} color="secondary">
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                            <Button onClick={() =>
                                this.CropImageBanner()
                            } color="primary">
                                Crop
                            </Button>
                        </DialogActions>
                    </Dialog>
                    :
                    null
                }
                <Stepper className="MuiPaper-root-custom" activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
                    {steps.map((label, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Step key={label}>
                                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                                <StepContent className="pb-3">
                                    <Typography>{getStepContent(index, this)}</Typography>
                                    <div className="mt-2">
                                        <div>
                                            <Button
                                                disabled={activeStep === 0}
                                                onClick={this.handleBack}
                                                className="jr-btn"
                                            >
                                                Back
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button
                                                variant="contained"
                                                color="primary"
                                                onClick={this.handleNext}
                                                className="jr-btn"
                                            >
                                                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                                            </Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </StepContent>
                            </Step>
                        );
                    })}

                </Stepper>
                {activeStep === steps.length && (
                    // <Paper square elevation={0} className="p-2">
                    /*<Typography>All steps completed - you&quot;re finished</Typography>*/
                    <div>
                        <Button onClick={this.sendNotification} disabled={!this.isFormValid} color="primary" style={{ "align-self": "flex-end", "border": "1px solid", "margin-left": "10px", "margin-bottom": "40px" }} size="small" className="col-md-2 col-2">Create</Button>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleReset} color="primary" style={{ "align-self": "flex-end", "border": "1px solid", "margin-left": "10px", "margin-bottom": "40px" }} size="small" className="col-md-2 col-2" color="primary">Reset</Button>
                )}

                {this.props.showMessage && NotificationManager.error(this.props.alertMessage) ?
                    <NotificationContainer /> : null
                }

                {this.props.showSuccessMessage && NotificationManager.success(this.props.successMessage)}
                <NotificationContainer />

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    showCompaignAlert: (message) => dispatch(showCompaignAlert(message)),
    CreateCampaign: (data) => dispatch(CreateCampaign(data)),
    hideMessage: () => dispatch(hideMessage()),
    hideCompaignAlert: () => dispatch(hideCompaignAlert()),
    showCampaignLoader: () => dispatch(showCampaignLoader())
});


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loader: state.Campaigns.loader,
    allWebsites: state.Websites.allWebsites,
    alertMessage: state.Campaigns.alertMessage,
    showMessage: state.Campaigns.showMessage,
    successMessage: state.Campaigns.successMessage,
    showSuccessMessage: state.Campaigns.showSuccessMessage,
});

export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles) (NotificationStepper)));
```

and following is my CreateWebsite

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {createWebsite, hideSuccessMessage, hideAlertCreateWebsite} from "../../../actions/Websites";
import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from "react-notifications";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import getCroppedImg from "../Send Notification/cropImage";
import Cropper from "react-easy-crop";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
    transparentBar: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        paddingTop: '25px',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    dialogPaper: {
        minHeight: '400px',
        maxHeight: '400px',
    },
};

class CreateWebsiteComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        title: '',
        url: '',
        logo: '',
        showDialog: false,
        crop: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        zoom: 1,
        aspect: 1,
        croppedAreaPixels: null,
        croppedImage: null,
    };


    handleChange = name => event => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };
    onFileChange = event => {
        this.setState({ logo: event.target.files[0] });
        this.setState({ showDialog: true})
    };

    createWebsite = (title, url, logo) => {
        let temp  = 'https://' + url;
        this.props.createWebsite({title, url , logo})

    };
    onCropChange = crop => {
        this.setState({ crop })
    };

    onCropComplete = (croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
        this.setState({croppedAreaPixels: croppedAreaPixels});
    };
    closeDialog = () => {
        this.setState({showDialog: false});
    };

    onZoomChange = zoom => {
        this.setState({ zoom })
    };

    CropImageBanner = async ()=> {
        const croppedImage = await getCroppedImg(
            URL.createObjectURL(this.state.logo),
            this.state.croppedAreaPixels,
            0
        );
        this.setState({ logo: croppedImage });
        this.closeDialog();
    };



    render() {
        if (this.props.showSuccessMessage) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.hideSuccessMessage();
            }, 100);
        }
        if (this.props.showAlertCreateWebsite_) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.hideAlertCreateWebsite();
            }, 100);
        }
        const { title, url, logo} = this.state;
        const openDialog = this.props.openDialog;
        const { classes } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <Dialog
                    classes={{paper: classes.dialogPaper }}
                    fullWidth={true}
                    maxWidth='md'
                    open={this.state.showDialog}
                    onClose={this.closeDialog}
                >
                    <DialogTitle>
                    </DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <div className="App-crop" >
                            <div className="crop-container-div">
                                <Cropper
                                    image={this.state.log}
                                    crop={this.state.crop}
                                    zoom={this.state.zoom}
                                    aspect={this.state.aspect}
                                    onCropChange={this.onCropChange}
                                    onCropComplete={this.onCropComplete}
                                    onZoomChange={this.onZoomChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="controls">
                                <Slider
                                    value={this.state.zoom}
                                    min={1}
                                    max={3}
                                    step={0.1}
                                    aria-labelledby="Zoom"
                                    onChange={(e, zoom) => this.onZoomChange(zoom)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.closeDialog()} color="secondary">
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={() =>
                            this.CropImageBanner()
                        } color="primary">
                            Crop
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
                <Dialog
                    open={openDialog}
                    onClose={this.props.closeDialog}
                >
                    <DialogTitle>
                        {"Create Website"}
                    </DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <FormControl className="w-100">
                            <TextField
                                style={{'margin-right': "10px"}}
                                className="col-md-11 col-11"
                                id="name"
                                label="Title"
                                value={this.state.title}
                                onChange={this.handleChange('title')}
                                margin="normal"
                                fullWidth
                            />

                            <TextField
                                style={{'margin-right': "10px"}}
                                className="col-md-11 col-11"
                                id="name"
                                label="URL"
                                value={this.state.url}
                                onChange={this.handleChange('url')}
                                margin="normal"
                                fullWidth
                                InputProps={{
                                    startAdornment: (
                                        <InputAdornment className='positionEnd' position="start">
                                            https://
                                        </InputAdornment>
                                    ),
                                }}
                            />
                            <div style={{"margin-top": "20px"}} className='col-md-11 col-sm-12 col-12 flex-class-custom'>
                                <span style={{"margin-right": "20px"}}>Icon: </span>
                                <div className="inputfile">
                                    Upload
                                    <input className='hide_file' style={{"width": "80%"}} type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
                                </div>


                                {this.state.logo ?
                                    <span>{this.state.logo.name}</span>
                                    : null
                                }
                            </div>
                        </FormControl>
                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={this.props.closeDialog} color="secondary">
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={() => this.createWebsite(title, url , logo)
                        } color="primary">
                            Create
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
                {this.props.showAlertCreateWebsite_ && NotificationManager.error(this.props.alertMessage)}
                <NotificationContainer/>

                {this.props.showSuccessMessage && NotificationManager.success(this.props.successMessage)}
                <NotificationContainer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    createWebsite: (payload) => dispatch(createWebsite(payload)),
    hideSuccessMessage: () => dispatch(hideSuccessMessage()),
    hideAlertCreateWebsite: () => dispatch(hideAlertCreateWebsite())
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loader : state.Websites.loader ,
    alertMessage : state.Websites.alertMessage ,
    showAlertCreateWebsite_ : state.Websites.showAlertCreateWebsite_,
    showSuccessMessage : state.Websites.showSuccessMessage,
    successMessage : state.Websites.successMessage
});



export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(CreateWebsiteComponent));
// export default CreateWebsiteComponent;
```